# What happends if I set "listenToOnce" triggers multiple times for the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When using Backbone, if I set same listener in a view multiple times (using `listenToOnce`), does it create multiple one-time-listeners for that same event, or just override the one?

```
eventThatMightHappenMultipleTimes: function () {
    this.listenToOnce(this, 'someEvent', this.someEventHandler);
},

...

foo: function () {
    this.trigger('someEvent');
}
```

I want to be sure that I don't leave any useless listeners behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it creates the same listener multiple times. You can test it easily:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenToOnce(this, 'someEvent ', this.logEvent);
    this.listenToOnce(this, 'someEvent ', this.logEvent);
    this.listenToOnce(this, 'someEvent ', this.logEvent);
    this.listenToOnce(this, 'someEvent ', this.logEvent);
  },
  logEvent: function() {
    console.log("'someEvent' has been fired!");
  }
});

var view = new SomeView();
view.trigger('someEvent');
```

Here is [a working demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/cucuxe/2/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will cerate multiple one-time-listeners for that same event.http://bit.ly/1EljaXf